# Web API Individual Accounts Register User

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am developing a ASP.NET Web API using ASP.NET Identity (Individual Accounts) for authentication/authorization. I am able to successfully login by making a call to `/token` URI.

All I want is to automatically sign in my user when he register himself to my application. I am able to do the half of the task by signing in the user in Register method using following code:

```
ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
ClaimsIdentity cookieIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.UserName);
Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity, cookieIdentity);
```

Is there a way I can return the same OAuth like response which I get when I make successful call to `/token`. Some thing like following:

```
{"access_token":"access-token","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":1209599,"userName":"username",".issued":"Sat, 22 Mar 2014 08:12:14 GMT",".expires":"Sat, 05 Apr 2014 08:12:14 GMT"}
```

Comment: I know this question is almost a year old ... but I have the same question. I notice that the provided answer was not the accepted answer. What are others doing in this case? I was planning to have the client-side registration function call the client-side login function for this. Would handling this on the server-side be better?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm facing same issue moments ago, I handled it in such an ugly way-- Inside Register method, I made another web request to access "/token", just after created the new user, and pass the latest username and password.

```
private string GetTokenForNewUser(string username, string password)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var host = Request.RequestUri.Scheme + "://" + Request.RequestUri.Host + ":" + Request.RequestUri.Port;
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(host);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            Dictionary<string, string> credential = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            credential.Add("grant_type", "password");
            credential.Add("username", username);
            credential.Add("password", password);

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(host + "token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(credential)).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }
        //if we go this far, something error happens
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

I don't think this is a good way to do so, but it just works.

Answer (score 0):

You can add payload for the token (it also depends on the token you are using). Then, you can also retrieve the payload value from the token during request.

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"], _config["Jwt:Issuer"], signingCredentials: credentials, expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
token.Payload["UserId"] = user.Id;
```